Best linear prediction of random vector
Given a random variable $Y \in \mathbb{R}$ and a random vector $\boldsymbol{X} \in \mathbb{R}^k$, the best linear predictor $\boldsymbol{X}^T \boldsymbol{\beta}$ of $Y$ ($\boldsymbol{\beta}\in \mathbb{R}^k$) is such that $\boldsymbol{\beta} = \operatorname{argmin}_{\boldsymbol{b}\in \mathbb{R}^k} \operatorname{E}[(Y - \boldsymbol{X}^T \boldsymbol{b})^2]$. One can show by calculation that $\boldsymbol{\beta} = (\operatorname{E}[\boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{X}^T])^{-1} \operatorname{E}[\boldsymbol{X} Y]$.
Now let $\boldsymbol{Y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a random vector. I would like to define in general a best linear predictor $\boldsymbol{\Gamma} \boldsymbol{X}$ that approximates $\boldsymbol{Y}$, where $\boldsymbol{\Gamma} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$ should have an expression similar to that of $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ after proper calculations, that is, $\boldsymbol{\Gamma} = \operatorname{E}[\boldsymbol{Y} \boldsymbol{X}^T] (\operatorname{E}[\boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{X}^T])^{-1}$. If it is possible, what should be the correct definition of such linear predictor?

Hint: consider how the solution might be related to the separate regressions of the components of $\mathbf Y.$

Another hint: you need to distinguish between expectations and expectations conditional on $\mathbf X.$  Your "best linear predictor" is a random variable (it's a function of $(\mathbf X,Y)$) but what you claim can be shown "by calculation" is a constant, contradicting your first assertion.
